# Equivalent of qqplot of R in Python

Tags: python, r

I am trying to compare 2 distributions in python using qqplots. In `R` it's straightforward to use `qqplot()` like so:

```
qqplot(beaver2$temp[beaver2$activ==1],beaver2$temp[beaver2$activ==0])
```

Which will compare 2 distributions. Is there similar way to do in **Python**?

```
Y=np.random.normal(0.5,0.1,1000)
Y_hat=np.random.gamma(0.5,0.2,1000)
```

One option is to get the residuals of 2 sets and plot a `qqplot` against `Normal Distribution`

Comment: can u post sample data please

Comment: Sure. I've added sample data. :)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about what you exactly want, but check if that helps you. You can use `sm` from `statsmodel.api` for qq plots.

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
pp_x = sm.ProbPlot(Y, fit=True)
pp_y = sm.ProbPlot(Y_hat, fit=True)
fig = pp_x.qqplot(line='45', other=pp_y)
plt.show()
```

with result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. There's a simpler way to do it - have posted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found there's a function `qqplot_2samples` provided by `statsmodels.api`

```
Y=np.random.normal(0.5,0.1,1000)
Y_hat=np.random.normal(0.5,0.2,1000)
import statsmodels.api as sm
sm.qqplot_2samples(Y,Y_hat,line='45')
plt.show()
```

[image: QQPlot for 2 Samples]